# how do I fixUnboundLocalError

Tags: python

I am making a game in python and I get this error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playerY' referenced before assignment

The code is:

```
import voyager200librarys

playerY = 1
playerX = 0
amountOfRows = 3

command = voyager200librarys.menu ("P Y C R A F T", ["Play", "Quit"])

if (command == "Play"):
    world = [0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,1,1]

    def printWorld ():
        index = 0
        indexCheck = 0
        
        for x in range(len (world)):
            voyager200librarys.printWithoutNewLine (" ")
            
            if (world [index] == 0):
                voyager200librarys.printWithoutNewLine (" ")
            
            if (world [index] == 1):
                voyager200librarys.printWithoutNewLine ("D")
            
            if (world [index] == -1):
                voyager200librarys.printWithoutNewLine ("&")
            indexCheck += 1
            
            if (indexCheck == 3):
                print ("")
                indexCheck = 0
            
            index += 1
    
    def mainMenu ():
        print ("")
        whatToDo = voyager200librarys.menu ("What To Do?", ["Move"])
        
        if (whatToDo == "Move"):
            movementControls ()
    
    def movementControls ():
        print ("")
        print ("Movement Controls:")
        print ("<   >   Ʌ")
        print ("")
        print ("|   |   |")
        print ("V   V   V")
        print ("")
        print ("1   2   3")
        print ("")
        command = input ("Plase Pick An Option: ")
        
        command = int (command)
        
        if (command != 1):
            if (command != 2):
                if (command != 3):
                    print ("Plase Pick A Valid Option Next Time.")
        
        if (command == 1):
            world [playerY * amountOfRows + playerX] = 0 #(The problem occurs here) 
            playerX -= 1
        
        if (command == 2):
            world [playerY * amountOfRows + playerX] = 0
            playerX += 1
        
        if (command == 3):
            world [playerY * amountOfRows + playerX] = 0
            playerY -= 0
    
    while (True):
        printWorld()
        mainMenu()
        world [playerY * amountOfRows + playerX] = -1
```

and I've tried swapping "playerX" and "playerY" but it doesn't fix it! Btw the game itself is a ripoff of minecraft, and if your missing any information ask me.

If anyone has answers please help!

P.S. A quick answer would be great.
P.S. It's python.

Comment: The error talks about "local variable 'playerY'"; that should give you a clue.

Comment: If you are going to assign a value to a global variable inside a function, then you must declare that by adding `global playerX, playerY` at the beginning of the function.  And by the way, saying "a quick answer would be great" just pisses people off.  If someone is going to answer, they aren't going to say "I think I'll wait 4 hours before responding."